# How would i go about clearing the text in this "CTkEntry" feild? (and one other question)

Tags: python, tkinter, new-operator

I know a little about coding, i've made some applications and macros in C++ and c# and kinda know what im doing, you can probably see what level im at by my code.

I was coding an application that tracks habits, and was wondering if I'm 1. doing this right, 2. how would I clear this entry field?

Code in question:[code!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVKnF.png)

the user should just be able to type and if they chose to, get rid of whatever text there is.

Also wondering if someone could give me the most basic understanding of "classes" using my code.

(Custom Tkinter)

```
def H_Add():
    global WinCounter
    global HAdd

    if WinCounter == 1:

        HAdd = ctk.CTkToplevel()
        HAdd.geometry("400x120")
        HAdd.title("Add Your Habit!")
        HAdd.attributes("-topmost", "true")
        HAdd.resizable(False,False)
        
        WinCounter += 1

    HLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(HAdd,
                          font=ctk.CTkFont(size=15, weight="bold"),
                          bg_color = "transparent",
                          text = "Add a Habit!"
                          ).place(x=150,y=2)
    HEntry = ctk.CTkEntry(HAdd,
                          placeholder_text= "Enter Your Habit Here!",
                          width=340,
                          ).place(x=30, y=40)
    HSave = ctk.CTkButton(HAdd,
                          text = "Save",
                          width=70,
                          fg_color="#303030",
                          ).place(x=298,y=80)
    HClear = ctk.CTkButton(HAdd,
                          text = "Clear",
                          width=70,
                          fg_color="#303030",
                      #-->command = HEntry.select_clear()<--- tried this? maybe i need to use classes?
                          ).place(x=142,y=80)
    HClose = ctk.CTkButton(HAdd,
                          text = "Close",
                          width=70,
                          fg_color="#303030",
                          ).place(x=220,y=80)
```

Comment: Something like `command = HEntry.select_clear` might be a step in the right direction (i.e. without the parentheses), as you want to assign the function itself, not the result of a call to the function. A question like "give me the most basic understanding of "classes" using my code" is like asking for someone to compress an object-oriented coding for Python into a comment or answer - you should really just read up on the subject a bit more and ask a more focused question. However, FYI: you're already using classes, you're just not aware of what they are well enough.

Comment: One problem with your code is that `.place` returns `None`.  You need to do it separately, `HClear = ctk.CTkButton(...)` / `HClear.place(x=142,y=80)`.

Comment: Please do not post code in an image. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) for why. Thanks!

Comment: @grismar, yup not sure why I asked for the understanding of classes last night however I appreciate all the answers you all have given. Tim Roberts, the issue was .place returning None, now I've just gotta figure out how to get the clear function working. again thanks, guys!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the help of @Tim Roberts by moving the .place() and the end of the code via HEntry.place(x,y).

```
    HEntry = ctk.CTkEntry(HAdd,
                          placeholder_text= "Enter Your Habit Here!",
                          width=340,
                          )
    HSave = ctk.CTkButton(HAdd,
                          text = "Save",
                          width=70,
                          fg_color="#303030",
                          ).place(x=298,y=80)
    HClear = ctk.CTkButton(HAdd,
                          text = "Clear",
                          width=70,
                          fg_color="#303030",
                          command=HCLR,
                          ).place(x=142,y=80)
    HClose = ctk.CTkButton(HAdd,
                          text = "Close",
                          width=70,
                          fg_color="#303030",
                          ).place(x=220,y=80)
    HEntry.place(x=30, y=40) # <---- Place is now separate as to not return None
```

I then defined a function:

```
def HCLR():
        CLR = HEntry.delete(0, last_index=300)
```

which clears the entry field from character 0 to 300.

lastly, the "clear" button uses command=HCLR, to clear the text field

```
HClear = ctk.CTkButton(HAdd,
                          text = "Clear",
                          width=70,
                          fg_color="#303030",
                          command=HCLR,
                          ).place(x=142,y=80)
```